# How to organize location directives in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have a bunch of URLs which share a common parent directory, e.g.

```
/content/a/.../...
/content/b/.../...
/content/c/.../...
```

What I'm currently doing is having a separate location block for each of them, but the actions performed inside the block are the same.

I wonder if it is more optimal to just have a single location directive for `/content/`, e.g.

```
location ^~ /content/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect   off;
}
```

But how should I deal with invalid requests such as `/content/d/...`, `/content/blah/`, etc?

Comment: how do you check if the request is invalid or valid?

Comment: @AndreiMikhaltsov, by invalid, I mean there is no resource (e.g. handlers, static files, etc) available for the requested url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try_file directive inside content location like:

```
location /content {
   try_files $uri $uri/ @pass =404;
}
location @pass {
  proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_redirect   off;
}
```

it will check file, @pass location and then return 404 if nothing found;

Answer (score 2):

If the list of valid resources is known and small, how about a regex match? Something like:

```
location ~ ^/content/(a|b|c|etc)/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect   off;
}
```